# Software for conversion from e3, e2, .d to Step or other Solidworks formats

Tags: 3d, file-conversion

In our company we need to convert old files which were developed with think 3D in Solidworks file format.
The solution seems to be the think design conversion but it requires the licence acquisition.
We don't want to pay a full licence which costs around 5/6k until November.

So the main question is: are there some tools for conversion of the e2, e3, .d files in other formats compliant with Solidworks?

Comment: solid works doesn't list any of those [file formats](https://help.solidworks.com/2022/english/solidworks/visualize/r_visualize_other_file_formats.htm#:~:text=Other%20File%20Formats%20%20%20%20Format%20,assembly%20informatio%20...%20%2020%20more%20rows%20). Have you tried another CAD software like freecad?

Comment: No we never tried free cad

Comment: Tried with free cad but i dose not support the think 3 file formats

Comment: [trial solidworks](https://my.solidworks.com/try-solidworks) may not include exporting but its worth it to see if even compatible

Comment: We already have solidworks sw but it's not compatible with these type of files

Comment: you mentioned these are solidwork file formats. Do you know what type of files these are/what program created them?

Comment: The files that we  try to convert are created by Think Design software

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135413/discussion-between-depperm-and-ion-stirba).